# Dont understand the next iteration for recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm learning to work with recursion and so far it went well with basic examples. However I want to calculate the factorial, but I don't understand what happened step-by-step. If I do it imperatively I understand it but I fail on this example:

`return x * fac(x-1);`  gives me back 5 * 4, so far soo good, but what happens now? Does it mean it become 20 now? So my next iteration would be then 20 * 19?

```
      const fac = (x) => {
        if(x <= 1) {
          return x;
        }
        return x * fac(x-1);
      };
      console.log(fac(5)); // 120
```

Comment: It's not 5*4, it's 5 * fac(4),

Comment: `fac(5)` = `5 * fac(5 - 1)` = `5 * 4 * fac(4 - 1)` = `5 * 4 * 3 * fac(3 - 1)` = `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * fac(2 - 1)` = `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * fac(1)` = `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1` since for `fac(1)` the parameter falls into `x <= 1` thus it's the terminal condition and it stops the recursion.

Comment: Ultimately, "factorial" of 5 is going to give you `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1` by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just walk through the logic.

```
1. fac(5) yields 5 * fac(4)
2. fac(4) yields 4 * fac(3)
3. fac(3) yields 3 * fac(2)
4. fac(2) yields 2 * fac(1)
5. fac(1) yields 1
```

substituting from bottom to top, you get

```
fac(5) = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand that part now and the difference between `4` and `fac(4)`. The steps look like:

```
5. 5 *       // ()
4. 4 *       // (20)
3. 3 *       // (60)
2. 2 *       // (120)
1. 1 *       // (120)
```

However, I have another example which i cant resolve step by step, while i can see the logic in the imperatively programming.

```
let fibo = (x) => {
  if(x<=2) {return 1;}
  return fibo(x-1) + fibo(x-2);
};
console.log(fibo(4));  //3
```

I cant resolve step by step what `return fibo(x-1) + fibo(x-2);` values this gives me each step.  On the imperatively programming it is

```
function fibonacci(num){
  var a = 1, b = 0, temp;

  while (num >= 1){
    temp = a;
    a = a + b;
    b = temp;
    num--;
  }

  return b;
}
console.log(fibonacci(4);  // 3
```

where the steps would be like

```
4. b = 1
3. b = 1
2. b = 2
1. b = 3
```

Comment: Just walk through the logic the exact same way as I did in my answer ... 1. fibo(4) yields fibo(3) + fibo(2), 2. fibo(3) yields fibo(2) + fibo(1), 3. fibo(2) yields 1, 4. fibo(1) yields 1 .... sub from bottom to top, you get fibo(4) = 1 + 1 + 1